# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/'

Tags: php

I am on my new dedicated server and i am getting this error always.

php version is 5.3.4

in php.ini extensions is empty and extension_dir is /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613

how can i fix this ?

thanks

EDIT

I checked that directory on ssh and it is empty but also extension variable is empty why it is warning me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your php needs to load some extensions that don't have the libraries installed.
you need to look where on your server they may be and change the location into php.ini or have them installed

if this is a new server and you ported the php is normal but is easy to fix

Comment: how can i search for them on server ?

Answer (score 1):

try following if you are using WHM/cPanel

```
/scripts/phpextensionmgr install PHPSuHosin
```